# Custom Gridview (Shelfview) in android

Tags: android, gridview

I am using Custom `Gridview` which looks like `Shelf` basically called `ShelfView`

For this I am using the tutorial http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2014/11/books-shelfview-in-android.html.

I am using images of size 75x75(dp) for `Gridview` custom row . The shelf background image doesn't appears for the 2nd row in `Gridview`.

Can anyone help me in this .[image]

Grid_row.xml

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ripple_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    app:rv_centered="true"
    app:rv_framerate="5"
    app:rv_rippleDuration="50">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_ninja_delights"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/chocolates_image"
        android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>

</com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

main.xml

```
<com.techmorphosis.Utils.BookshelfView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view_ninja_delights"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/inventory_footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/realtive_header"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="3"

        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp">

    </com.techmorphosis.Utils.BookshelfView>
```

BookshelfView.java

```
public class BookshelfView extends GridView {

    private Bitmap background;

    public BookshelfView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public BookshelfView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public BookshelfView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        //Set the background image of the ShelfView panel.
        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.im_ninja_delights_rack);
    }

    //Draw a background in the screen and create multiple panels using height & width.
    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int top = getChildCount() > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getTop() : 0;
        for (int y = top; y < getHeight(); y += background.getHeight()) {
            for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += background.getWidth()) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(background, x, y, null);
            }
        }
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
```

im_ninja_delights_rack.png

[image]

after changing height to 100

[image]

Actual require layout

[image]

`Gridview` height set to match_parent

[image]

@  Андройд Андройд

[image]

Comment: look in debug what returns background.getHeight()

Comment: ok ..let me see this

Comment: or change  background.getHeight()  to 100, for example to see result

Comment: please see my updated results

Comment: ok, let i try to help you. w8 2 min

Comment: okay ... i am waiting

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ripple_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:rv_centered="true"
    app:rv_framerate="5"
    app:rv_rippleDuration="50">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_ninja_delights"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/chocolates_image"/>

</com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

Comment: with what height set to ?

Comment: hello waiting for you Sir :(

Comment: im here. Set height background 100 and try to use this for your row item

Comment: tried... but second row image appears over the border line

Comment: please see the image with heading " @ Андройд Андройд  "

Comment: hm, dont know why looks like that :(

Answer (score 0):

Its a height problem of the GridView. The The GridView wraps upto a given height. If `layout_height="wrap_content"` is given for the GridView, it will show minimal height.

Some tips:

1. Add a padding_bottom in your Custom GridView, so the view port may extend a little.
2. Override the onLayout and onMeasure methods in your implementation to adjust the height according to number of children.

Comment: Please see my updated results of height set to match_parent

Comment: are you okay with it?

Comment: No Sir...The second row's height is greater than the first one , so image is not exactly placed on the rack line . The third row will be greater than the second